# Unidentifiable alert to "cancel transfers"

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, file-transfer, data-transfer

About 3 months ago, I purchased a Dell XPS 13 running Windows 8. Ever since, whenever I try to shut down/restart my machine, I get an alert that looks like this:

[image]

This doesn't happen each time but it happens once in a while. The following is the sequence of events that produces this:

1. Using a web browser, for instance, Google Chrome (in deskptop mode). I close the web browser when I am done.
2. On the desktop, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to bring up the prompt that let's you switch user or shut down and so forth.
3. Before the prompt comes up, I get the alert like the one in the screenshot.

I think this may be caused by something Microsoft Upload Center is doing but I'd like to know the exact cause.

---

Edit 1 : I have now noticed this happen independent of the usage of Chrome

Comment: Run ProcessExplorer, use the crosshair, move it to the Window and now ProcessExplorer highlights the process which shows this message.

Comment: @magicandre1981: This string is found in Shell32.dll, but your suggestion is useful to use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).

Comment: Do you have any sync program installed?

Comment: Nope, but I do see Microsoft Office Upload Center running in the background

Comment: You should in this case have the Upload Center yellow icon in the notification area. If you are not using SkyDrive and/or the Office "Save to Web", read [Disable Microsoft Office Upload Center](http://superuser.com/questions/560972/disable-microsoft-office-upload-center). See also [this link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-office_other/how-do-i-remove-microsoft-office-upload-center/b1d6bc7a-7561-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?msgId=df8b8abe-0462-e011-8dfc-68b59).

Comment: I do use SkyDrive but it doesn't seem like this popup appears at the times when I do use it (unless of course it is doing something in the background that I am not aware of)

Answer (score 1):

Note that when closing the web browser, it may actually still be running in the background.

Consider using the menu and doing `Quit` instead of closing the window.

This is particularly valid if you do large file transfers with your browser.

Alternatively I would look into the process tree for active processes or possible sources of such transfers.

Comment: Doesn't Chrome quit a download if it is progress and the browser has been closed? I have checked the processes after quitting Chrome and it definitely isn't in there

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be caused by SkyDrive and/or the Office "Save to Web".

See the article [Disable Microsoft Office Upload Center](https://superuser.com/questions/560972/disable-microsoft-office-upload-center) and try it out,
making sure that you can reverse all settings.

If this fixes the problem then this is a bug in SkyDrive.
You might try to :

1. find an alternate way of using SkyDrive not from inside Office
2. use another cloud storage than SkyDrive
3. do forcefully shut down the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I tired the other answers on here and nothing seemed to help. I then installed Windows 8.1 and am not seeing this issue anymore.