# 100% processor utilization with multiple executions of CSISYNCCLIENT.EXE and MSOSYNC.EXE

Tags: windows-7, cpu, office365

When I install MS Office 365, my processor runs systematically at 100%. When I look at Windows7 task manager, two processes are executed in multiple times : CSISYNCCLIENT.EXE and MSOSYNC.EXE. 
Would you have some solutions in order to solve that problem ?
Thank you very much for your answer
Laurent

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable Microsoft Office Upload Center](http://superuser.com/questions/560972/disable-microsoft-office-upload-center)

Answer (score 0):

I go to command line and type

```
taskkill /F /IM msosync.exe
taskkill /F /IM CSISYNCCLIENT.exe
```

That will kill all the processes.