# Office : Processing dialog... What is that?

Tags: microsoft-office, office365, onedrive

Since I am using OneDrive, every time I save a document locally have this weird dialogue that pops out several time during 3-4 seconds. Interestingly the first message is `Contacting the server` which shouldn't occur when saving documents locally.

[image]

What are these windows and how can I disable them?

Comment: [windows - Disable the auto-upload that occurs on each save - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/943636/disable-the-auto-upload-that-occurs-on-each-save)?

Comment: Unclear: Local or OneDrive?